# get bytes representation of number as a decimal string without intermediate string object in python

Tags: python

If I have `x = 123`, I would like to generate the bytes object `b'123'`.

I know I can accomplish this with `str(x).encode('ascii')` or `bytes(str(x), 'ascii')`.

My question is, is it possible to do this without having to create an intermediate `str` object?

Comment: I suppose you could break the int into a list of digits (repeated `divmod(x, 10)`). Then the ASCII equivalent of each digit (i.e. the byte that needs to go into the bytes object) is `d + 0x30`.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do this? The intermediate string isn't a particularly significant expense, and short of writing your own extension module, anything you try to do to avoid the string object is probably going to be *more* expensive.

Comment: The answer to the question is "Yes, but not with anything built in".

Comment: it is possible - but not something that should worry you. the cost for that is negligible. More important, it is possible to encode a number to "real number in bytes" using the "to_bytes" method in integer objects.

Comment: `bytes_object = decimal.Decimal(x).to_eng_string().encode()`

Answer (score 2):

It is possible using `%` formatting:

```py
encoded = b"%d" % x
```

I'm not sure if that is more performant for that particular case. Although I suspect it is if you are doing other formatting as well, for example something like:

```py
percentage = b"%d%%" % n
```

#### Update

Building on the comments from @mark-tolonen:

```
❯ python -m timeit -r 50 "'{}%'.format(1234).encode()"
2000000 loops, best of 50: 162 nsec per loop


❯ python -m timeit -r 50 "b'%d%%' % 1234"             
5000000 loops, best of 50: 82.3 nsec per loop
```

so it looks like if you need to do interpolation, this method is probably more performant.

Comment: `py -m timeit -r 50 "b'%d' % 123"` -> `1000000 loops, best of 50: 225 nsec per loop`

Comment: `py -m timeit -r 50 "str(123).encode()"` -> `1000000 loops, best of 50: 215 nsec per loop`

Answer (score 0):

While the method below is not advisable performance wise, it actually does the job without any intermediate string or running `str(123)` implicitly. Knowing the offset in the ASCII table I use `int.to_bytes(...)` to create the bytes.

```
def digitize(n, base=10):
    if n == 0:
        yield 0
    while n:
        n, d = divmod(n, base)
        yield d

def int_to_bytes (n):
    # numbers have an offset of 48
    x_bytes = b''.join([(48+i).to_bytes(1, 'big') for i in digitize(n)])
    # reverse
    return x_bytes[::-1]

x = 123
print(int_to_bytes(x))
```

Output:

```
b'123'
```

So, how slow is it actually. Let's use `timeit.repeat()` and compare it to:

```
def int_to_bytes_str_0(n):
    return bytes(str(n), 'ascii')

def int_to_bytes_str_1(n):
    return str(n).encode('ascii')

def int_to_bytes_str_2(n):
    return b"%d" % n

def int_to_bytes_str_3(n):
    return decimal.Decimal(n).to_eng_string().encode()
```

Results per call:

| function | time per call (µs) |
| --- | --- |
| int_to_bytes | 1.01 |
| int_to_bytes_str_0 | 0.26 |
| int_to_bytes_str_1 | 0.24 |
| int_to_bytes_str_2 | 0.16 |
| int_to_bytes_str_3 | 0.38 |

So `%` formating wins clearly wins. But suprisingly the method above is only a factor of 6 slower. If you are not using the conversion billions of times you will be fine either way.